how to connect IBM db2 database using loopback request node in App connect enterprise
By using loopback request node I am trying to connect with db2 but while deploying the application on server I am getting error as

The LoopBackRequest node received an error from LoopBack when attempting to connect to the data source name 'mydb2dsn'. Detail: '\?\C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQSI\node_modules\loopback-ibmdb\node_modules\ibm_db\build\Release\odbc_bindings.node is not a valid Win32 application. \?\C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQSI\node_modules\loopback-ibmdb\node_modules\ibm_db\build\Release\odbc_bindings.node'.

I installed node js on my system and also I tried with different versions of node js but still when I am trying to deploy the application on server getting the error.
npm install loopback-connector-db2

by using this command I am trying to install loopback connector for db2 it is generating one folder i.e ibm_db which contains
C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQSI\node_modules\ibm_db\build\Release\odbc_bindings.node
this file "odbc_bindings.node" causing error while deploying the application on server.
